# Изменение значения переменной в Java-файле

Tags: java, метапрограммирование

Есть Java-файл. Допустим с именем `Example.java` и в нем, есть код:

```
public class EXAMPLE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Как мне изменить значение `x = 10` на `x = 30` через другую Java-программу?

**Как должна, в теории, произойти изменение(как я это вижу):**

Другая java-программа (допустим, `Example2.java`) открывает файл `EXAMPLE.java`, считывает все строки и находит ту самую - `x = 10`. Далее эта строка удаляется и на месте нее появляется `x = 10`. Из-за того, что информация должна куда-то записываться во время такх изменений - она будет записываться в файл `EXAMPLE_temp.java`. После завершения процесса изменения переменной, `EXAMPLE_temp.java` переименовывается в `EXAMPLE.java` и генерируется новый `EXAMPLE.class`. Дальше, при компиляции новой версии файла `EXAMPLE.java`, в консоли должно протсто вывестись:

`30`

**Почему это важно?**
В нынешний момент, чтобы изменить ОДНО ЧИСЛО в файле, мне приходится держать отдельно *.txt документ, в который я произвожу изменение данных.

**Почему я не пробовал сам "поэкспериментировать/почитать"?** .
Потому что мне интересно узнать, что могут посоветовать знающие и прошаренные люди. Мне интересен разный подход к решению данной проблемы

*(Простите за офф-топик, но без этого никак.)*

Comment: Нужно более конкретно задать вопрос. А то вон jEdit  - другая ява-программа. Открыть файл в этом редакторе и заменить. Но я предполагаю, что программа сама должна все сделать. Всегда ли переменная зовется х? Всегда ли класс зовется Example? Ит.д.

Comment: @Эникейщик я добавил подробное описание действий. Данное описание должно помочь Вам для понятия сути проблемы

Comment: Этот вопрос должен войти в топ 10 упоротых вопросов. Уважаемый автор, в java вполне нормальным считается выносить конфигурацию в отдельный файл (чаще xml).

Comment: Какова цель этих манипуляций?

Comment: вы скажите, чего вы хотите в конечном итоге, и мы вам объясним, как этого добиться без всяких манипуляций с кодом. Код не должен модифицироваться в процессе работы - это правило выстрадано многими поколениями программистов. И не слушайте самураев, советующих использовать AST. Путь самурая - это всегда дорога к смерти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работа с исходным кодом как с текстом - путь недостойный самурая. *Знающие и прошаренные* люди советуют использовать API компилятора для разбора исходника в [абстрактное синтаксическое дерево (AST)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE), модификацию этого дерева и его компиляцию всё тем же API компилятора.

**Example.java**

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

**JavaSourceFromString.java**

```
import java.net.URI;

import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;


/**
 * Класс эмулирующий для компилятора файлы исходного кода
 * и позволяющий компилировать код прямо из памяти
 */    
class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    private final String code;

    public JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.','/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
        return code;
    }
}
```

**Translator.java**

```
import com.sun.source.util.JavacTask;
import com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask;
import com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacElements;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context;


// Класс обхода и модификации AST
public class Translator extends TreeTranslator {
    private final TreeMaker treeMaker;
    private final JavacElements elements;

    public Translator(JavacTask task) {
        Context context = ((BasicJavacTask) task).getContext();
        treeMaker = TreeMaker.instance(context);
        elements = JavacElements.instance(context);
    }

    // Встречено определение переменной    
    @Override
    public void visitVarDef(JCTree.JCVariableDecl tree) {
        String varName = tree.getName().toString();
        if ("x".equals(varName)) {  // Переменная имеет имя "x"
            // Подменяем определение, заменяя литерал
            result = treeMaker.VarDef(tree.getModifiers(), tree.getName(), tree.vartype, treeMaker.Literal(30));
        }
        else {
            super.visitVarDef(tree);
        }
    }
}
```

**Parser.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

import com.sun.source.tree.CompilationUnitTree;
import com.sun.source.util.JavacTask;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree;


public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        // Считываем исходный файл
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects("Example.java");
        JavacTask javac = (JavacTask) compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, fileObjects);
        Translator translator = new Translator(javac);
        List<JavaFileObject> sources = new ArrayList<>();
        // Парсим исходный файл в деревья
        for (CompilationUnitTree tree : javac.parse()) {
            // Модифицируем деревья
            ((JCTree.JCCompilationUnit) tree).accept(translator);
            // Сохраняем результат в память
            sources.add(new JavaSourceFromString("Example", tree.toString()));
        }
        // Компилируем
        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, null, null, null, null, sources);
        task.call();
    }
}
```